# Is Eric Weinstein's copyright protection of Geometric Unity in the spirit of Science?

Tags: etiquette, science, academic-freedom

In (Dr.) Eric Weinstein's [Geometric Unity: Author’s Working Draft, v 1.0](https://geometricunity.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/Geometric_Unity-Draft-April-1st-2021.pdf) he has a footnote on the first page:

> The Author is not a physicist and is no longer an active academician, but is an Entertainer
> and host of The Portal podcast. This work of entertainment is a draft of work in progress
> which is the property of the author and thus may not be built upon, renamed, or profited from
> without express permission of the author. ©Eric R Weinstein, 2021, All Rights Reserved.

I am perturbed by the phrase "may not be built upon". Perhaps I do not understand what this phrasing means in context, however *prima facie* it strikes me as preferring control over the idea rather than its growth.

I do not have anything to add to Eric's ideas, but let's exemplify hypothetically. Let's say that I have found a choice of 'ship in a bottle operator' that accomplishes what Eric Weinstein had hoped for, but also resolves any [potential issues with complexification](https://timothynguyen.files.wordpress.com/2021/02/geometric_unity.pdf). It seems that in Eric's view, even with citation to his work, I should not publish such a development of his ideas unless he has given it an explicit approval.

Does Eric's stance go against the scientific spirit of [seeing farther on the shoulders of giants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_on_the_shoulders_of_giants) and [academic freedom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_freedom)?

Comment: Interesting that on the same page he has this note, he's also infringing on the copyright of Escher, and doesn't even bother attributing him.

Comment: The document is dated April 1, 2021.

Comment: Shortly before this document appeared, a physicist and a mathematician posted a rebuttal to Weinstein's theory (eg blogged about here: http://backreaction.blogspot.com/2021/03/guest-post-problems-with-eric.html). I wonder if this is related.

Comment: He positions himself as an entertainer and declares his work as a work of entertainment, in which case the special aspects of entertainment law, at least in the US, might be invoked, e.g. derivative works. Interested in seeing how this plays out.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The author holds copyright and is, in essence, claiming "all rights reserved". But he can't claim more than what the copyright law protects.

You can't "own" ideas, but your expression of them can be protected by copyright. Patent law gives a limited (in time) exclusive right to exploit the idea, but not ownership of the idea itself.

Priority of discovery is a matter of etiquette, and should be acknowledged, but, again, doesn't imply ownership. Acknowledgement protects against claims of plagiarism.

Most likely here is that if you just avoid copyright infringement you can do what you like with extension. But cite the work, of course.

Note, however, that, for most purposes, copyright is a matter of civil law unless you try to mass produce someone else's copyrighted work. Being in the right doesn't necessarily mean you can't get sued. Some IP owners are relentless with lawsuits and can make claims beyond the law - a form of intimidation. It can be expensive to defend yourself against even an unjust lawsuit.

---

For a more explicit answer, I find it hard to impute a motive to him. The language is a bit strong (stronger than usual), but it has no real world effect other than to reserve all rights. In fact, this is one case where keeping it private might have been a better option, whereas sharing it is more in the "spirit" of science.

Comment: For an example, if Newton was working today, he could copyright the "Principia Mathematica", but not calculus.

Comment: Copyright is very much the matter of criminal law in many countries. E.g. Czech criminal code 40/2009 §270, "Who infringes... will be punished by jail for up to 2 years and by...

Comment: @VladimirF, I'm surprised. I know it varies a lot, but haven't come across that variation.

Comment: @Buffy It is mainly targeted against for-profit pirates. Sellers, and manufacturers,  of unauthorized copies of software, music, books and so on. https://www.europol.europa.eu/crime-areas-and-trends/crime-areas/intellectual-property-crime

Comment: @VladimirF, I clarified, I hope.

Answer (score 8):

It should be noted that all this notice does is to re-state the rights and restrictions that are already the default ones by law. In other words, it does not actually have any effect.

The rights and restrictions would be exactly the same if this notice was not present.

Also note that everything *you* write, for which you do not explicitly grant additional rights will have the same rights and restrictions. That is the reason why Stack Overflow, Inc. requires you to license all content you create on this site to them, for example.

Comment: Could you please specify in which jurisdiction and according to which source(s) an author has the right to forbid work that builds upon their own ideas? This would strike me as somewhat extreme.

Comment: @JochenGlueck Pretty much all jurisdictions, if you take the actual wording and not the one changed by you. Because by changing it you also changed the meaning a lot.

Comment: @JochenGlueck: Where in that notice does it say anything about "ideas"? The notice only says "This **work** of entertainment". The term "work" is a precisely-defined technical term in copyright. The term "build upon", not so much, the technical term for the result is "derivative work", and there is no single technical term for the process, only terms for specific kinds of processes (e.g. transform, modify, translate, recast, alterate, abridge, condense, arrange, …), so "build upon" sounds about as good a term as any. This is part of the Berne Convention, so it should apply to practically all …

Comment: … jurisdictions that have copyright at all. All countries that are members of the WTO have protections of similar level, which is pretty much all countries that are "interesting" from a copyright perspective (in that, countries that have not signed either the Berne Convention or one of the WTO treaties, have such a small market that the fact that they don't recognize copyright in the same way doesn't matter). Eritrea, Kosovo, Marshall Islands, Palau, and Palestine are more or less the only ones. Even North Korea is a signatory.

Comment: @Nobody and JörgWMittag: Thanks a lot for your replies! I did indeed not pay sufficent attention to the precise wording when I wrote my comment. The original post seems to be concerned whether this notice could be interpreted in a way that prevents others from obtaining new scientific results that rely on the author's ideas, in case that the author does not permit usage of his ideas. I was under a similar impression at first, but I acknowledge that this was due to my merely colloquial rather than legal understanding of the involved terminology.